# how to disable one of control item of form array in angular 9

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, formarray

I have a form and in this form in this form I have a `formArray`.

```
  InitialFrom(): void {
this.addElectricMoneyFG = this.fromBuilder.group({
  hasAccountNumber: [this.showMoreInfo],
  moreAccountInfo: ['', null],
  description: [''],
  locales: this.fromBuilder.array([]),
  published: [false]
})
```

the `formArray`:

```
selectedLanguage(langId): FormGroup {
return this.fromBuilder.group({
  languageId: [langId],
  name: [''],
  moreAccountInfo: ['']
})
```

}

When clicking on the toggle I want, `moreAccountInfo` in the `formArray` to be `disabled` .

I wrote this code:

```
this.f.hasAccountNumber.valueChanges.subscribe(check => {
  this.showMoreInfo = check;
  if (check) {
     this.f.locales['controls'][0]['controls']['moreAccountInfo'].enabled;
  } else {
    this.f.locales['controls'][0]['controls']['moreAccountInfo'].enabled;
  }
  this.f.locales.updateValueAndValidity();
  this.cdRef.detectChanges()
})
```

It didn't work, threw this error:

```
this.f.locales.controls[0].controls.moreAccountInfo.disabled is not a function
```

Comment: Did you try `this.f.locales.controls[0].controls.moreAccountInfo.disable()`? Check out the [official doc](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#disable).

Comment: @riorudo show me this error `Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.`

Comment: Can you try if this works: `this.f.get('locales').constrols[0].get('moreAccountInfo').disable()`?Otherwise you can try to cast it to an FormArray  `get locales(): FormArray {
    return <FormArray>this.f.get('locales');
  }` and than you can use `this.locales.constrols[0].get('moreAccountInfo').disable()`

Comment: @riorudo this is `f`=>`get f() {
    return this.addElectricMoneyFG.controls
  }`

Answer (score -1):

You need follow this method.

```
 (<FormArray>this.testForm.get("locales")).controls[0].get('moreAccountInfo').disable()
```

If you want to disable whole form of index 0.

```
(<FormArray>this.testForm.get("locales")).controls[0].disable()
```

***[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/disableformarray)***

Comment: this is my `f` => `get f() {
    return this.addElectricMoneyFG.controls
  }`